Failed to register landscape-client on ubuntu 20.04 - broker.bpickle
I've tried to install landscape-client (3.02-0ubuntu1~20.04.3) on a Ubuntu 20.04
When registering it shows failure output:
Request a new registration for this computer now? [y/N]:y
Traceback (most recent call last):
Failure: twisted.internet.error.Connect Error: An error occurred while connecting: 2: No such file or directory.

I've tried reinstalling and tried registering again, but still gave the same error output:
sudo apt update
sudo apt purge landscape-client landscape-common
sudo rm -r /var/lib/landscape
sudo rm -r /var/log/landscape
sudo apt install landscape-client

This is the result when checking systemctl:
Aug 02 21:52:05  landscape-client[1378899]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/landscape/client/deployment.py", line 153, in get_versioned_persist
Aug 02 21:52:05  landscape-client[1378899]:     persist = Persist(filename=service.persist_filename)
Aug 02 21:52:05  landscape-client[1378899]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/landscape/lib/persist.py", line 83, in __init__
Aug 02 21:52:05  landscape-client[1378899]:     self.load(filename)
Aug 02 21:52:05  landscape-client[1378899]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/landscape/lib/persist.py", line 141, in load
Aug 02 21:52:05  landscape-client[1378899]:     raise PersistError("Broken configuration file at %s" % filepath)
Aug 02 21:52:05  landscape-client[1378899]: landscape.lib.persist.PersistError: Broken configuration file at /var/lib/landscape/client/broker.bpickle
Aug 02 21:52:05  landscape-client[1378899]: 2024-08-02 21:52:05,336 INFO     [MainThread] Manager stopped with config /etc/landscape/client.conf
Aug 02 21:52:05  landscape-client[1378899]: 2024-08-02 21:52:05,336 INFO     [MainThread] Monitor stopped with config /etc/landscape/client.conf
Aug 02 21:52:05  systemd[1]: landscape-client.service: Succeeded.

How do you fix this broker.bpickle?
Python version is default - 3.8.10
